# gtk infinite loop exit

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

I have a script which has a record and stop button, the record button does an infinite loop, but it also blocks the other button (stop button). All I wanted to build is a process which starts at click of record button and stops are click of stop button. Here is the script:

```
# -*- Mode: Python; coding: utf-8; indent-tabs-mode: nil; tab-width: 4 -*-
### BEGIN LICENSE
# This file is in the public domain
### END LICENSE

from locale import gettext as _

from gi.repository import Gtk # pylint: disable=E0611
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('recordme')

from recordme_lib import Window
from recordme.AboutRecordmeDialog import AboutRecordmeDialog
from recordme.PreferencesRecordmeDialog import PreferencesRecordmeDialog

class RecordmeWindow(Window):
    __gtype_name__ = "RecordmeWindow"
    record = False

    def finish_initializing(self, builder): # pylint: disable=E1002
        """Set up the main window"""
        super(RecordmeWindow, self).finish_initializing(builder)

       self.AboutDialog = AboutRecordmeDialog
       self.PreferencesDialog = PreferencesRecordmeDialog

       # Code for other initialization actions should be added here.
       self.button1 = self.builder.get_object('button1')
       self.button2 = self.builder.get_object('button2')

    def on_button1_clicked(self, widget):
        while(not self.record):
             print 'button1 clicked'
             while gtk.events_pending():
                gtk.main_iteration(False)
```

Any ideas about this problem ?

Comment: Where `self.record` is set?

Comment: self.record is set to False just on the third of the code above.

Comment: Why not thread the callback that takes long time? That's what I've always have done with long callbacks. Check how to init threads correctly with gtk first though

Comment: @deinonychusaur Its not about long time, its about an infinite loop, which is blocking another button from stopping the loop, but I am not sure how to thread the infinite loop then.

Comment: do you want your code to busyloop (or do something useful in a loop) while recording?

Comment: Ok, why not let first button toggle second button sensitivity state? `self.button2.set_sensitive(not self.button2.get_sensitive())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your record functionality is cpu-intensive and/or may block and/or needs soft realtime assurance, I would recommend moving it off to a separate "worker" thread.

Then, create a window and your buttons.

Here, when "record" is clicked, I signal the worker to start recording; when "stop" is clicked, signal worker to stop; Optionally, when stop is clicked, terminate the main loop if you want your app to exit.

Additional control logic to terminate the app when window is closed and terminate the worker thread correctly is at the very bottom.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import logging
import threading
from gi.repository import Gtk


class Worker(threading.Thread):
    should_record = False
    quit = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.quit:
            if self.should_record:
                logging.warn("recording...")
                # cpu-intensive code here
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.start()
        hb = Gtk.Box()
        self.add(hb)
        record = Gtk.Button("Record")
        stop = Gtk.Button("Stop")
        hb.add(record)
        hb.add(stop)

        def command(arg):
            self.worker.should_record = arg

        record.connect("clicked", lambda _b: command(True))
        stop.connect("clicked", lambda _b: command(False))
        # optional, if you want to quit the app on stop as well
        stop.connect("clicked", lambda _b: Gtk.main_quit())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = MainWindow()
    try:
        # optional, if you want to support close window to quit app
        main.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        main.show_all()
        Gtk.main()
    finally:
        main.worker.quit = True
        main.worker.join()
```

#### old stuff

Ideally you wan to use `Gtk.main()` instead of `Gtk.main_iteration()` in Gtk+ 3.

In Gtk+ 2, module name was `gtk` rather than `gi.repository.Gtk`.

Then you can quit wit with:

> Gtk.main_quit
>
> ```
> def main_quit()
> ```
>
> The Gtk.main_quit() function terminates the current main loop level
>   started by the most recent call to the Gtk.main() function. The
>   nesting level of the main loop is reduced by calling this function.

You can have several nested main loops, in which case, you'd have to quit each of those.

Alternatively you can also use `gtk_dialog.run()` then default action for a button is to exit the loop.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still gives NameError: global name 'gtk' is not defined
message.

Comment: I tried importing it, but gives a long stack trace. I have a doubt if Gtk import is conflicting with gtk? You could see my import in my question.

Comment: To be honest, even I dont have a clue about it, as I am a noob to it, but I could give it a try.

Comment: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html#main-loop-and-signals  apparently all you want is in `Gtk` now in `Gtk+ 3`. My example is a bit outdated... I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: I saw this doc. and at one point did try to use widget.connect, but nothing fruitful. I will give a try once more with different logic, between someone commented above that using a thread would be a good idea, would it solve the problem? I am actually trying to build a screen recorder.

Comment: you want to connect your signals to individual buttons

Comment: Yes, I want to connect the signals to the buttons, say a record button would start an infinite loop and a stop button should exit that loop. I will give a try to what you have suggested in your answer.

Comment: perfect! I made it work with Gtk.main() as well, and this example is a bonus for me! Thanks.

Comment: Just one more quick question, as your code is CPU intensive, what about the code which I am using as in my question? I think that would be efficient, correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: you didn't publish your record code, I can hardly comment on that.

Comment: Its already in my question. The on_button1_clicked code would be doing recording activity within indefinite loop.

Comment: Single-threaded code is always at least marginally more efficient -- multithreaded program wastes some time on context switches, and in case of Python, sometimes notable amount of time. However your code is susceptible to jitter and lag -- you don't know how long `gtk.main_iteration()` might take. This jitter may be too much for [sound?] recording application. Multithreading [mostly] decouples gui from recording. Furthermore if python-gtk is coded well, multithreaded program may benefit from 2nd processor core. Take is as a trade-off.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I was wondering if I could run the recording tasks atleast for taking video could be run in the background. How could I run a background task using this Gtk lib? If you could just point me where to look into for that would be awesome.

Comment: And one other thing, as your said, single-threaded code is always more efficient, but if I tend to use it, then I cant get away with jittering, as my gui would freeze. I guess I have to do it using background process as mentioned in my previous comment. Your suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered similar programs in WX, which is also event based. The best (and possibly only) way I found to solve the problem is to create a function that runs on a timer during the main loop. Mine ran periodically, but you could also just set it to wait and close the loop when you run your function. In GTK, you have to do this with another module, "gobject". Here is an example of a method that runs periodically in GTK.

```
import gobject

class gtk_object(object):
    def __init__(self):
        gobject.timeout_add(100, self.my_function)
    def my_function(self):
        #do something here, like stopping the loop or having a timer to stop the loop
        return True
```

Comment: timeout and idle functions are very useful indeed.

Comment: but if I use it to build my screen recorder then I would have a delay, and then if I make video out of it, it would be quite visible.

Answer (score 1):

GTK+ (as most UI toolkits) is event-based. That means it runs internal "event loop" - a loop that collects and processes events, such as handling user input and redrawing windows. All event handlers are dispatched from main loop. In order to process events, loop must be "spinning".

In your example, you are blocking main loop:

```
def on_button1_clicked(self, widget):
    while(not self.record):
         print 'button1 clicked'
```

as long as this function does not finish, control does not return to main loop so it cannot process other events, or redraw windows.

You can add this snippet form [PyGTK FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq03.007.htp) in order to allow main loop to process event in the meantime:

```
while gtk.events_pending():
  gtk.main_iteration(False)
```

Comment: Thanks..I will have a look at it.

Comment: I tried it, but import gtk is throwing an error, I think I am using different GTK.

Comment: What version of gtk are you using?

Comment: Actually I really dont have a clue as I am very new to it. I am developing an app using glade on ubuntu 12.10. How to check the version of it? I surely remember that I didnt had to install anything in particular to gtk.

Comment: I have edited my question to show how I am using your suggested code snippet.

Comment: And what happens then?

Comment: Did you `import gtk`?

Comment: I have edited my question with the imports. The code is importing Gtk, if that is equivalent to gtk?